# Does importing sub-module affects previous imports?

Tags: python, pylint

Consider,

```
# create files for test
mkdir package
touch package/__init__.py
touch package/mod.py
```

```py
import package

def foo() -> None:
    import package.mod
```

I thought the inner `import package.mod` should not affect the outer `import package`. However, a pylint check tells me, (the snippet was saved to `foo.py`)

> foo.py:4:4: W0621: Redefining name 'package' from outer scope (line 1) (redefined-outer-name)

Does this suggest that the inner `import package.mod` would redefine the outer `import package`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sub-package imports import all parent packages. You can try this yourself

```
import os.path

print(os)
```

So

```
import package.sub_package
```

does have the side-effect of defining `package`

Comment: Thanks for letting me know - this is surprising to me! I will accept the answer when I can accept an answer in 7 minutes.

Comment: It's definitely a weird behavior since it's a side effect

Comment: Yeah, a line from The Zen of Python just floated across my mind: 'Explicit is better than implicit.' Haha!